# Storing data from a .dat file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store data from a `.dat` file. Using a while loop and `ifstream` I've managed to get it to print out exactly what I need, but I need to store what it's printing out so I can perform arithmetic operations on them. It seems like it's such a short leap from printing the info to storing the info, but I just can't figure it out.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
int main()
{
    char name;
    cin.get(name);

    ifstream inStream;
    inStream.open("grade.dat");

    while (name != ' ')
    {
        inStream.get(name);
        cout << name;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Push your data onto a vector.

Comment: What's in the the .dat file? Also if your names are longer than one character (which i assume they are) you may want to consider string.

Comment: just as paddy mentions,u can store it in a STL vector.just define a `vector<char> output`，using vector's push_back method

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put them all in some sort of data structure. I'd recommend one of the [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) data structures since you're using C++. Fortunately for you, someone already asked how to read text from a file and store it in an [STL `vector`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28STL%29#Vector)!

[Reading line from text file and putting the strings into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365013/reading-line-from-text-file-and-putting-the-strings-into-a-vector)

Comment: [The STL is obsolete; you're using the C++ Standard Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about/5205571#5205571)

Comment: @paddy - Thanks for the clarification. I had no idea there were people that opposed calling the parts of the standard library that came from STL as STL, nor did I realize so many people think that STL is the _entire_ C++ standard library.