# Most efficient way to read lines from text file to std::vector<string>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, fstream

The common way to add lines extracted from a text file into a std::vector< std::string > where every element of vector correspond to a file's line is something like these example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8365024/7030542

```
std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> myLines;
while (std::getline(myfile, line))
{
    myLines.push_back(line);
}
```

or also

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12506764/7030542

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
for (std::string line; std::getline( ifs, line ); /**/ )
    lines.push_back( line );
```

Does exist a most efficient way to do that like avoid the auxiliary string?

Comment: both solutions are good and efficient

Comment: Those two solutions are precisely equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

Don't overthink it:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;
while(std::getline( ifs, line ))
    lines.push_back(std::move(line));
```

Note that the moved from `line` is in a valid, but indeterminate state, so calling `std::getline` is fine because that will replace the `std::string`'s contents (whatever they may be) completely, eradicating any indeterminate state that was left behind by the `move`.

Comment: Maybe about move semantics you right, but  you are missing the point. It doesn't need another string to do the same work.

Comment: Another thing, in your code, when the loop run for the second time you try to add new data into string line that is in indeterminate state.

Comment: @Menashe Yes, the second loop iteration will set the content of a valid  `std::string` object with indeterminate contents. Since `std::getline` replaces the `std::string`'s contents, there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: Then you create a new string every cycle. I don't see any advantage to use a move semantic here.

Comment: The fact that the string contents don't need to be copied on `push_back` is where the move makes a difference.

Comment: But you lose the advantage of move when you recreate the string line every cycle with getline.

Comment: @MenasheRosemberg You appear to be confused.  Assuming lines long enough to avoid SBO, each line a buffer is allocated.  This buffer is then moved into the vector.  No "advantage" is lost.

Comment: I really don't understand how to avoid an auxiliary string cannot be better. The codes used has 4-5 steps (1-create auxiliary string, 2-write data on it, 3-create new element into vector, 4-copy/move auxiliary string to this new element, 5-for move semantic the getline need to rebuild the auxiliary string) instead avoid auxiliary string with 3 step (1-create new element into vector, 2-write data on it, 3-when the loop finished erase last element).

Comment: Huh, all my years using this "pattern" and I never thought to move out of the string variable. heh

Comment: @yakk I read the specification of getline in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ and getline doesn't use buffer instead "Each extracted character is appended to the string as if its member push_back was called. Move semantic here make no sense because you need to recreate line every loop. Better use a old copy.

Comment: @MenasheRosemberg [Better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) -- it clears the passed in string, then appends.  I have no idea why you think this has to do with "better use a old copy" rather than move-from.

Answer (score 1):

@rubenvb's answer is great.

As an alternative

```
bool get_line_into_vector( std::istream& is, std::vector<std::string>& v ) {
  std::string tmp;
  if (!std::getline(is, tmp))
     return false;
  v.push_back(std::move(tmp));
  return true;
}

std::vector<std::string> lines;
while(get_line_into_vector( ifs, lines ))
{} // do nothing
```

This is rubenvb's solution with the temporary moved into a helper function.

We can avoid the small buffer optimization sized copies of characters with this:

```
bool get_line_into_vector( std::istream& is, std::vector<std::string>& v ) {
  v.emplace_back();
  if (std::getline(is, v.back()))
    return true;
  v.pop_back();
  return false;
}
```

this can (in an edge case) cause an extra massive reallocation, but that is asymptotically rare.

Unlike @pschill's answer, here the invalid states are isolated to within a helper function, and all the flow control is centered around avoiding those invalid states from leaking.

The nice thing is that

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
while(get_line_into_vector( ifs, lines ))
{} // do nothing
```

is how you use it; which of these two implementations you use is isolated to within the `get_line_into_vector` function.  That lets you swap between them and determine which is better.

Comment: For the move semantic solution, the getline’s specifications [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and [cpprefference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) says it doesn't use buffer but "Each extracted character is appended to the string as if its member push_back was called".

Comment: And also getline expect a reference to a string then pass to it a string in an undefined state is not a good programming practice.
Also, ‘recreated’ tmp string every cycle to move it again doesn’t seem more efficient then keep tmp alive during all cycle like the old fashion.

Comment: Then avoid an auxiliary string is a great solution when you need to make a memory reservation (vector::reserve) before read the data (vectors those will get new element frequently for example), otherwise use an auxiliary string is better.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid temporary variables, you can use the last vector element as buffer:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines(1);
while (std::getline(ifs, lines.back())
    lines.emplace_back();
lines.erase(--lines.end());  // remove the buffer element
```

Comment: This is not recommendable: it's much harder to comprehend and may not be any faster than moving a temporary `string` (as in rubenvb's answer).

Comment: Yakk, thanks for your response. Can you explain a little more how it may cause extra memory allocation and when lines is in invalid state? And furthermore, how to wrap the emplace back and back to make a more efficient code?

Comment: @menashe: in The worst case, your last real line fills up The vector' storageoplossingen, causing the extra emplaced line to reallocate the whole vector, and doubling its memory use. With The inkt result of The last element being deleted again. Granted, that's an edge case, bit it can happen.

Comment: It may happen, but if your vector will get data frequently or it is a big vector and also will receive new data, it is a good practice make a good reservation to this vector. In this cases (maybe others too ) that solution seems pretty nice.

Comment: @MenasheRosemberg To ping someone, place an @ before their name.  Simply stating their name won't do that (unless it is in response to a post by them, as opposed to a comment).  `lines` is in an "invalid" state on every line except after the `while` condition (but before the body) and after `lines.erase`; by "invalid" I mean not in a sensible intermediate state between the initial state and the final one (it has an extra empty string at the end).  Such states in my experience cause bugs.  The extra memory allocation is because we make `lines` 1 larger than it has to be, then discard the extra.